# Linq query to select all the nodes based on an attribute value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
<Category id=1>
<MyLines>
      <Line GroupID="0" Cache="15" />
  <Rect GroupID="0" Cache="16"/>
  <Ellipse GroupID="0" Cache="16"/>
</MyLines>
```

My XML document contains many Category tags. Could you please let me know what is the best way to get each of the sub elements of MyLines whose Cache = 16 and remove them.

I am looking to achieve this using linq.

I was trying as below:

```
       var q = from node in doc.Descendants("MyLines")
                let attr = node.Attribute("Cache")
                where attr != null && Convert.ToInt32(attr.Value) == 16
                select node;
        q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

Comment: please have a look at my edits to the question

Comment: Do you have a special reason to use LINQ? To me it looks like an XSL-transformation is the thing to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the following code:

```
string xml = 
@"<Category id=""1"">
<MyLines>
    <Line GroupID=""0"" Cache=""15"" />
<Rect GroupID=""0"" Cache=""16""/>
<Ellipse GroupID=""0"" Cache=""16""/>
</MyLines>
</Category>";

void Main()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    doc.Descendants("MyLines")
    .Elements()
    .Where(el => el.Attribute("Cache").Value == "16") 
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(el => el.Remove());

    doc.Root.ToString().Dump();
}
```

It prints:

```
<Category id="1">
   <MyLines>
      <Line GroupID="0" Cache="15" />
   </MyLines>
</Category>
```

The problem is that you were looking for the `Cache` attribute on the `MyLines` elements instead of on the `MyLines` elements' children.

Comment: @KishoreBorra, I don't know if there was a typo in my original post, but I tested it and reposted.  Try the updated code

Comment: Yes. The above code is working. But in my case I have multiple Category tags with a parent tag with a name <MyDocument xmlns="urn:Mylines.xsd" >. would it be creating any problem?

Comment: I figured out the solution. Yes the namespace would cause an issue while querying. It needs to be queried little differently. Please refer to the below link.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/bf061026-8dce-4845-8294-8acde88f4402/